# Компоновка изображений как в VK

Tags: android

Хочу сделать компоновку изображений как пост в ВК, в зависимости от количества изображений. Наставте на верный путь)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас вёрстка поехала, нижний ряд кнопок не входит ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решал такую же задачу. Только компоновка была зависима от ориентации и разрешения экрана. За основу брал эту библиотеку https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView. Недавно наткнулся еще на такую интересную библиотеку https://github.com/adhamenaya/AndroidMosaicLayout

Answer (score 4):

Нужно динамически создать три LinearLayout с горизонтальной ориентацией и программно добавлять в них картинки. В первом LinearLayout с одной ImageView, второй Linearlayout с свойством sumWeight = 2 и двумя ImageView c layout_weight = 1, после чего третий layout с sumWeight = 4 и четырьмя ImageView с layout_weight = 1.

Все три linearLayout надо программно засунуть в заранее вертикально-ориентированный LinearLayout из ресурсов.

У второго и третьего LinearLayout нужно проставить фиксированную высоту, а у первого wrap_content.

Естественно надо программно проверять, хватает ли у нас картинок на все три ряда, либо можно создать универсальный цикл, который проверит, какой минимальной степенью двойки является количество картинок, и создавать лэйотов столько, во сколько возведено двойка

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую)