# Мозайка фотографий как ленте ВКонтакте

Tags: java, android, алгоритм, view

Как правильно и оптимизировано выстроить фотографии как в оф приложении ВК или в Кейт мобайл? 
Вот например скрины. 
Видно 10 фоток, и все они красиво выстроены, мне нужно реализовать так же.

**У кого какие идеи?**

Библиотеки где ListView отображает так фотографии не подходит. Я не хочу в Feed ListView в каждый блок добавлять ещё один ListView для фото.

Я нашел код бывшего разработчика ВКонтакте, для такого красивого вывода фотографий, но применить его не смог https://gist.github.com/zhukov/1934001

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @pavlofff да, это то что нужно, но библиотеки с ответа подходят скорей только для отображения списка фотографий с галереи или альбомов юзера. Или Вы мне предлагаете в ListView использовать в каждом блоке ещё один ListView ?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482397/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-vk/482674#482674